# why is jQuery async AJAX call blocking other HTTP calls

Tags: asp.net, http, jquery, asynchronous

I am loading an HTML table through jquery ajax async call. Say for 5 persons, their data will be loaded through async ajax call. The ajax call hits the server five times and asynchronously displays data as they are received.
The rows contain a link to open a popup for displaying the person's records.

Problem is when i am clicking on a link while the other data is still loading, the popup opens and displays a blank page until the remaining ajax calls have been completed.

How can I resolve this issue?

This is my jquery code:

```
$.ajax({
  type:'POST',
  url:'Default.aspx',
  data:JSON.stringify(jsonParams),
  contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
  async:true,
  dataType:'Text',
  success: function(response){ //paste the data to the html table }

});
```

This is my server side code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  StreamReader r = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream, Request.ContentEncoding);
  string jsonStr = r.ReadToEnd();
  MyJsonObj obj = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<MyJsonObj>(jsonStr);
}
```

Comment: show some code to see what u´ve tried

Comment: can you provide us with some code because an async call is just that, asynchronous. Once the request is sent, its all on the server to handle.

Answer (score 0):

seems some limit from web server or browser ( *N* connection per IP?